# Is there a possible way of using Zipkin without Sleuth?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I have some distributed micro services written in Spring Boot and I am using RabbitMQ. I want to track my requests. Is there a possible way of tracking without using Spring Cloud or Sleuth

Comment: any reason why you do not go for the sleuth with Zipkin ?

Comment: My boss said we won't use Spring Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://zipkin.io/pages/tracers_instrumentation.html) Spring Cloud Sleuth is the only tracer that supports messaging.

Answer (score 1):

Brave is the library spring cloud sleuth is built on, therefore you could make it work without sleuth: https://github.com/openzipkin/brave

Just to clarify though, Sleuth doesn't force you to use any of the rest of the spring-cloud components. It is `spring-cloud` because it is one of the "cloud native" spring technologies